# How to increase letter/s in a word with strings, nested loops?

Tags: python, string, function, return

I'm wondering if someone can write out a 'beginner' function, where def is the starting piece of the function. I don't have an understanding of it at all, to be honest. I've been reviewing videos, interactive games and taking notes, but can't seem to create a function that even points toward error types that tell me how to rewrite my attempts, because I'm assuming too many things are wrong.

I'd like to write out 'greetings,' and have the end result allow for the number of e's to continue expanding 2, 4 or 6 times.

I don't know how to create this at all, so for the 'include the problem' prompt to the side of creating this new post, I can't share much, really, aside from this half formed attempt that I'm probably heading in the wrong direction for. Extremely blind guesses have question marks:

```
num_a = ??? "gr", letter_e, "tings") ???

def greetings(num_a):
    for i in range(num_a):
        if num_a <= 6:
        return("greeeeeetings!")
        
greetings()
```

I don't know *how* to try to solve this. It's interactive homework, but when I try running anything (that looks more cobbled together/doesn't include '???') the page just shows fail, in place of explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The ability for a function to return a SERIES of things is a bit advanced.  You will learn about `yield` later, which is a better way to solve this, but for now:

```
def greetings(num_a):
    collect = []
    for i in range(num_a):
        s = 'gree' + 'ee'*i + 'tings'
        collect.append(s)
    return collect

print(greetings(6))
```

Output:

```
['greetings', 'greeeetings', 'greeeeeetings', 'greeeeeeeetings', 'greeeeeeeeeetings', 'greeeeeeeeeeeetings']
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach, using counter and printing to terminal.

Code:

```
def greetings():
    counter = 2
    while counter <= 6:
        print('gr' + 'e' * counter + 'tings')
        counter += 2
greetings()
```

Output to Terminal:

```
greetings
greeeetings
greeeeeetings
```